# Basis for Eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the real matrix $\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}
7 &3  &-4 \\ 
 -2&-1  &2 \\ 
 6&2  &-3 
\end{pmatrix}$ and let $\beta \in M_n (\mathbb{C})$ be the same matrix but considered as a complex matrix (so over the complex numbers)

**Find the basis of the corresponding Eigenspace**

I found found the eigenvalues to be:

$\alpha$: over reals and then only the value $\lambda_1=3$

$\beta$: over complex and then the values $\lambda_1=3$,  $\lambda_2=i$ and  $\lambda_3=-i$

How would I proceed to find a basis for the Eigenspaces of the two matrices$

Comment: find the kernel of $\alpha-\lambda I$

Comment: Find the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, we can find the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = i$ as follows: compute
$$
\beta - \lambda I = 
\pmatrix{
7-i &3  &-4 \\ 
 -2&-1-i  &2 \\ 
 6&2  &-3-i }.
$$
We can row-reduce this matrix to get the reduced row-echelon form
$$
\pmatrix{1 & 0 & -1/2 - i/2\\0 & 1 & i\\ 0 & 0 & 0}.
$$
Conclude that the kernel of $A - \lambda I$ (i.e. the eigenspace) is spanned by the vector (i.e. eigenvector) $v_i = (1/2 + i/2, -i, 1)^\top$. In other words, the set $\{(1/2+i/2,-i,1)^\top\}$ forms a **basis** of the eigenspace associated with $\lambda = i$.

The other two basis (each a set with one vector) can be computed in a similar fashion.

Actually, because $A$ has real entries, we can use our result for $\lambda = i$ to get the eigenvector for $\lambda = -i$:
$$
Av_i = iv_i \implies \overline{Av_i} = \overline{iv_i} \implies A \overline{v_i} = -i \overline{v_i}.
$$
So, we can take $v_{-i} = \overline{v_i} =(1/2 - i/2, i,1)^\top$.

Comment: Okay so - The basis is the eigenvectors corresponding to the different eigenvalues. The cardinality of the basis of $\alpha$ will be $1$ and for $\beta$ be 3 (since they have 1 eigenvalue and 3 eigenvalues)?!.  If I understand correctly. All that is left to do is to find the eigenvector for $\lambda = 3$ and I got the basis for both eigenspaces, right?

Comment: @bymathformath Your second sentence is wrong. $\beta$ has three different eigenvalues, so it has $3$ different eigenspaces. Each eigenspace has its own basis, and each basis contains exactly one vector. You are correct in saying that $\alpha$ has only one eigenvalue, which means that it only has the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda = 3$.

Comment: okay I see! So all that is left is to find the eigenvector spanning the eigenspace of $\lambda =3$, correct?

Comment: @bymathformath Yes, that's right

Comment: and thus in total have 4 basis for both matrices

Comment: That's right. You have $3$ for $\beta$ and $1$ for $\alpha$. The one that you have for $\alpha$ is the eigenspace for $\lambda = 3$, which is also one of the eigenspaces for $\beta$.

Comment: I am only used to having 1 basis for 1 space or matrix so this is really new for me. Thanks a ton!

Comment: 1 small question. How did you read off that $v_1$ was the eigenvector?

Comment: We're looking for the kernel of $M = A - \lambda I$. In other words, we're looking for the solution to $Mx = 0$. If you write out the system of equations, I think it'll be clear how you might find the eigenvector. In particular, I set $x_3 = 1$ and then solved for $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: great I foun the remaining one to be ${(1,0,1)}$

Comment: @bymathformath Perfect that's exactly right

Comment: Thanks a ton - I will of course accept the answer but have a small question: How would one say this? i.e there is 3 eigenspaces where the eigenspace for the eigenvalue 3 is shared for both $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and the eigenspaces for the eigenvalue $i$ and $-i$ is only spaces of $\beta$ (??).

Comment: That works. Alternatively, I would say that $\beta$ has three eigenspaces, one for each of its eigenvalues $3$ and $\pm i$. $\alpha$ has only one eigenspace corresponding to its eigenvalue $3$. In fact, it's not technically correct to say that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same eigenspace associated with $3$; for $\alpha$, the eigenspace is the set of real multiples of $(1,0,1)$ while for $\beta$, the eigenspace is the set of complex multiples of $(1,0,1)$.

Comment: I see - makes perfect sense.