# Quick clarifying question regarding eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose a $3 \times 3$-matrix $A$ has real entries. Consider the 2 cases over real and complex numbers. Over the real numbers the eigenvalue 3 is the only one. over the complex numbers the eigenvalues $3, i, -i$ appear. Is the eigenspace and associated eigenvector(s) for the eigenvalue 3 the same exact ones or are they different since the matrix associated with the eigenvalues are over different numbers?

Comment: [Is this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3965749/81360) also yours, or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: The Eigenspace associated to the Eigenvalue $3$ is made of the solutions of $Ax=3x$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann We probably have the same assignment as I am in a really big class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v$ denote a non-zero real vector for which $Av = 3v$. Technically speaking, the eigenspace associated with $\lambda = 3$ for the real matrix $A$ (or the associated linear map over $\Bbb R^3$) is the set of *real* multiples of $v$. That is, the eigenspace is
$$
\{kv : k \in \Bbb R\}.
$$
The eigenspace associated with $\lambda = 3$ for $A$ considered as a complex matrix (or for the associated linear map over $\Bbb C^3$) is the set of *complex* multiples of $v$. That is, the eigenspace is
$$
\{kv : k \in \Bbb C\}.
$$

Comment: so technically speaking this is 2 different eigenvalues in terms of their association with their matrix $A$ over different numbers.

Comment: @mathstudent23 These are two different **eigenspaces** that are associated with the same matrix $A$. However, both of these are associated with the same eigenvalue (in particular to $3$).

Comment: got it, thanks.